# Cannot get json data with google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get json data and add it to spreadsheet, 
But i cannot get json data with google-apps-script.

```
function doPost(e) {
  try{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

    var params = JSON.parse(e.postData.getDataAsString());
    var time = params.time;
    var event = params.event;

    sheet.appendRow([event],[time]);

  }catch(e){
    sheet.appendRow([e]);
  }   
}

function execDoPost() {
  //Post data of json
 time  = new Date();
 var e = {
    parameter : {
      "time":time,
      "event":"test"
    }
 };
 doPost(e);
}
```

Error message is `TypeError: Unable to call undefined method "getDataAsString"`.
I tried the following method.

`var params = e.parameter;`

I could only get the data  "undefined"
and i have allowed authorization for specific Google services.
Thank you for reading!(Sorry for my poor English.)

I want to insert the following data.

```
{
    "index": 1,
    "age": 38,
    "registered": "Tuesday, July 9, 2019 7:01 PM"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "age": 37,
    "registered": "Saturday, April 28, 2018 9:00 AM"
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "age": 21,
    "registered": "Thursday, January 17, 2019 6:31 PM"
  },
  {
    "index": 4,
    "age": 33,
    "registered": "Friday, April 20, 2018 12:41 PM"
  }
```

In addition, we plan to put names, email addresses and etc.

Comment: Would you be able to share some of the raw JSON that you're trying to append? Please feel free to redact any confidential information that you may have.

Comment: Try wrapping it in square brackets `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still bit weak when it comes to JSON so I used this little dialog to play with it in Google Apps Script.

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='<html><head>';
  html+='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
  html+='</head><body><textarea id="txt1" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>';
  html+='<br /><input type="button" value="SendData" onClick="sendData();" />';
  html+='<script>function sendData(){var data=$("#txt1").val();google.script.run.loadData(data);}</script>';
  html+='</body></html>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function loadData(data) {
  Logger.log(data);
  var dt=JSON.parse(data);
  Logger.log(dt);
  var vA=[];
  dt.forEach(function(obj) {
    vA.push([obj.index,obj.age,obj.registered]);
  });
  Logger.log(vA);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA)
}
```

I started with this:

`[{"index": 1,"age": 38,"registered": "Tuesday, July 9, 2019 7:01 PM"}, { "index": 2,"age": 37,"registered": "Saturday, April 28, 2018 9:00 AM"},{"index": 3,"age": 21,"registered": "Thursday, January 17, 2019 6:31 PM"},{"index": 4,"age": 33,"registered": "Friday,April 20, 2018 12:41 PM"}]`

And this was my scripts output:

[image]

and with this you can run it as a webapp:

```
function runOne(mode) {
  var mode=mode||'dialog';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>';
  html+='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
  html+='</head><body><textarea id="txt1" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>';
  html+='<br /><input type="button" value="SendData" onClick="sendData();" />';
  html+='<script>function sendData(){var data=$("#txt1").val();google.script.run.loadData(data);}</script>';
  html+='</body></html>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  if(mode=='dialog') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
  }else{
    return ui;
  }
}
function doGet() {
  return runOne('web');
}
```

[JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)